# Why not deal four cards, two must be mucked, before the first bet?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I'm told in a six person game there's only a 1/6 chance of playing any player seeing a flop.

Why not deal more cards, three or four?, choose two, before the first bet to increase the number of plays and therefore the appeal to the public?

Comment: Like emphyrio pointed out, if everybody's range is stronger then you will obviously open tighter yourself. Players per flop will remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't increase much the frequency at which players see a flop. It would mostly just make the average hands stronger.

In PLO (pot limit omaha) you play with 4 cards all the way, and players do see flops a bit more but not that much more (and mostly because the difference of potential equity between 2 hands is closer on average than in hold'em, not because it's easier to make boats or quads).

Otherwise the variant you describe actually does exist already, although I forgot its name. Not Irish poker nor mexican, but they're also somewhat related 4 cards dealt variants afaI remember.

Other than that,  players seeing a flop with an average 1/6 frequency  only happens at very nitty tables with mostly regs, or in full ring. On average it must be close to 1/5 for high lvl regs in 6max .

Comment: (I don't understand why making the average hand stronger doesn't mean more likely to see the flop.)

Comment: @RandyZeitman If everyone runs twice as fast or you more likely to win the race?

Comment: Well thinking about that I'll say that finishing the race is perhaps the most basic requirement to be in the race.

Comment: It's all about relative hand strength. In a 9-ring game you would seldom play A-4 offsuit under the gun, while in Head's up play it is a standard opening. In both situations the absolute value of A4 is the same. What changes is the relative value, in relation to what other players are holding on average.

Comment: Well I think this is a good post, but just to add to this, I do think it does increase the frequency at which bad or new players see flops mainly because they no longer know what is a good hand. As you said it makes the average hand stronger but many players who make the shift from hold'em to omaha struggle to realise a good holdem hand means little in PLO. Good answer though +1

Comment: Gotcha koita.  I may have presumed most tournament tables play the same number of people.  Grinch, that is certainly the position I am coming from... as a complete novice.

Answer (score 3):

We have a variant game of what you're describing already. It's called Irish Poker (4 cards get rid of two cards after the betting round on the flop, before the turn card is put out), or Pineapple (any of the pineapple variants) where you get 3 cards and discard one on a certain street dictated by the variant.

Or just make your own variant for a homegame.

Comment: Gotcha thanks  Can you attest that both of those result in more playable hands?

Comment: I commented on Emphyrio's answer, I'll give you this one, the extra cards give the illusion of more playable hands, but in reality if you apply what's strong in hold'em to these variant games where you have multiple cards you can get yourself into bad situations. If it's a cheap pot sure your hands become way more playable, but as was mentioned above all hands become stronger which means to call someone who has raised you in turn need a much stronger hand now. If you can see flops for free yeah absolutely you'll have much more playable hands more times than not, but so will your opponents.

Answer (score 1):

Poker is not a card game. There are hundreds of variations played with cards and many not played with cards. The only thing that makes poker poker is betting against other players when you and the other player(s) hold an unknown thing. With that in mind the answer to your question is simply you can play any combination of cards (or other things) that you can dream up.